# Show Tag Details checkbox misbehaving on new Tags page

Tags: bug, tags

### On initial load:

[image]

### After checkbox is checked:

[image]

### After this point, changes in checked state have no effect.

[image]

Comment: I do not see this magic checkbox; not here, not on Stack Overflow, not on Gaming where I have a ♦. How do you find this thing? It's actually [a fairly desirable item](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82540/i-dont-like-the-new-tag-page/82565#82565).

Comment: I don't think it's a shop, *I want to know how I can get this magic checkbox*. It'll really make my life easier on Gaming, so I'm curious why you have it and I cannot find it at all.

Comment: @GraceNote: Not a shoop, I swear. (comment box vomited on me)

Comment: @GraceNote: Go to StackOverflow, click the Tags link (dark grey box next to Questions and Users at the top).  You found a tag details checkbox!

Comment: I don't see them either on both Meta and SU @Grace

Comment: [I mentioned I don't see it on Stack Overflow](http://i.imgur.com/O6962.png).

Comment: Pfft.  [You can't see it because you're wimps.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83748/eeeek-how-does-this-question-have-28-and-growing-close-votes-without-being-cl/83752#83752)  It takes a MAN to see that checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think thats because of this userscript?

[Stack Overflow Tag Manager](https://stackapps.com/questions/2062/stack-overflow-tag-manager)

Comment: I think you're right.

Comment: Now I know you're right.